# Enabling the Log4j 1.x bridge

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, system-properties

How to set the system property “log4j1.compatibility” to a value of “true” and How to set the Log4j 1 system property “log4j.configuration” to the location of the log4j 1 configuration file. I have tried through command line prompt the following command

*java -Dlog4j1.compatibility="true"* and
*java -Dlog4j.configuration="file:C:Users\Public\log4j.xml"*

Comment: The syntax is correct and should work. Do you have `log4j-1.2-api` in your classpath?

Comment: yes i have added the dependency